# How to (or why can't I) add a plain .xaml file to my Visual Studio solution and edit it within?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

**Status**

I have the following (Visual Studio 2017) solution configuration:

- *created a new solution* with one `.csproj`ect for post-build commands
- added several other `.csproj`ects to the solution via *add existing project*
- now I want to add a plain `.xaml` file, which works via *add an existing item* to the solution, but throws the error:

  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Problem**

The  item still appears, but a double-click to open it throws the same error and does not let me edit it.

**Unwanted fixes**

I can prevent this error by two ways (which I do not want):

- rename the `.xaml` files to e.g. a `.xaml.txt` file ending (and name them back within the post-solution-build commands)
- put the `.xaml` files into an own `.csproj` folder with a `.cs` file only defining the empty `namespace ThisIsMyGraphicsElement { }` and a `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file

**So my question is**

*How can I add and edit a plain `.xaml` file to my Visual Studio solution?*

**Edit**

Here is an example code:

```

```
<UserControl 

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="410" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid Background="#FFe5e5e6">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Margin="150,140,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366.865" Margin="0" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="24" Text="Live happily ever after...&#xA;" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```

As mentioned in comments/answers, adding a new (empty) `.xaml` file and pasting the code did not work as well.

Comment: What about just Add-> and choose a XAML file type and just paste your xaml into it? It sounds like it's expecting the corresponding .cs file to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks for the note, but I tried this as well, and it throws the same error...

Comment: In that case I would ask what's in the XAML file? Is there something in it trying to reference something that isn't available like say another resource or a namespace or something?

Comment: I added code from within one file which did not work to be imported nor pasted into a created one.

Comment: Ok, so the thing is though your error explains itself pretty bluntly. Somewhere in there is a reference to an object that can't be found. Find that object reference and you've found your culprit.

Comment: Ok, I will try some more simple designs and update the question once I have more ideas about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is happening here. You could try to create a new XAML within your project and then paste the XAML from the file you want to include. That's what I would try.

Edit: Not being able to comment.... I'm not the first to suggest this.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer to the comment on the original question, as well as my updated question.